# Additional sourceCollection for responsive images in TYPO3 7.6

Tags: typo3, typoscript, responsive, typo3-7.6.x

Is it possible to implement additional `sourceCollection` code for rendering responsive images in extensions. I have configured code for standard `tt_content.image.20.1.sourceCollection` and it works fine.

Here is my `TypoScript` code:

```
tt_content.image.20.1.layout {
  srcset {
    element.wrap = <img src="###SRC###" srcset="###SRC### ###WIDTH###w,###SOURCECOLLECTION###" sizes="|"###PARAMS######ALTPARAMS######SELFCLOSINGTAGSLASH###>
    element = (min-width: 1020px) 800px, (min-width: 740px) 460px, calc(100vw - 20px)
  }
}

    tt_content.image.20.1.sourceCollection >
    tt_content.image.20.1.sourceCollection {
      tiny {
        width = 160
        maxW < .width
        srcsetCandidate = 160w
      }
      extrasmall {
        width = 320
        maxW < .width
        srcsetCandidate = 320w
      }
      small {
        width = 460
        maxW < .width
        srcsetCandidate = 460w
      }
      normal {
        width = 600
        maxW < .width
        srcsetCandidate = 600w
      }
      medium {
        width = 780
        maxW < .width
        srcsetCandidate = 780w
        quality = 60
      }
      large {
        width = 920
        maxW < .width
        srcsetCandidate = 920w
        quality = 60
      }
      extralarge {
        width = 1100
        maxW < .width
        srcsetCandidate = 1100w
        quality = 60
      }
      huge {
        width = 1200
        maxW < .width
        srcsetCandidate = 1200w
        quality = 60
      }
    }


lib.responsiveImage {
    default = IMAGE
    default {
        file.import.current = 1
        altText.data = field:altText
        titleText.data = field:titleText
        layoutKey = srcset
        layout.srcset < tt_content.image.20.1.layout.srcset
        sourceCollection < tt_content.image.20.1.sourceCollection
    }
    specialBig < .default
    specialBig {
        layoutKey = srcset
        layout.srcset {
            element.wrap = <img src="###SRC###" srcset="###SRC### ###WIDTH###w,###SOURCECOLLECTION###" sizes="|"###PARAMS######ALTPARAMS######SELFCLOSINGTAGSLASH###>
            element = (min-width: 1020px) 521px, (min-width: 740px) 460px, calc(100vw - 20px)
        }

        sourceCollection { 
          tiny {
          width = 160
          maxW < .width
          srcsetCandidate = 160w
          }
          extrasmall {
          width = 320
          maxW < .width
          srcsetCandidate = 320w
          }
          small {
          width = 460
          maxW < .width
          srcsetCandidate = 460w
          }
          normal {
          width = 600
          maxW < .width
          srcsetCandidate = 600w
          }
          medium {
          width = 460
          maxW < .width
          srcsetCandidate = 780w
          quality = 60
          }
          large {
          width = 460
          maxW < .width
          srcsetCandidate = 920w
          quality = 60
          }
          extralarge {
          width = 520
          maxW < .width
          srcsetCandidate = 1100w
          quality = 60
          }
          huge {
          width = 600
          maxW < .width
          srcsetCandidate = 1200w
          quality = 60
          }
        }
    }
}
```

And `FluidTemplate` part:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.responsiveImage.default" data="{image.uid}"></f:cObject>
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.responsiveImage.specialBig" data="{image.uid}"></f:cObject>
```

The images from `lib.responsiveImage.default` part are rendered correct but from `lib.responsiveImage.specialBig` whole `sourceCollection` is ignored and on the output i have only that:

```
<img src="fileadmin/img/img.jpg" srcset="fileadmin/img/img.jpg 800w," sizes="(min-width: 1020px) 521px, (min-width: 740px) 460px, calc(100vw - 20px)" alt="alt-text" title="title-text">
```

Comment: In general, this is perfectly possible. There must be some syntax error somewhere. Did you check the TypoScript Object Browser to see if everything is applied correctly? Could you post `### Additional Config ###` here?

Comment: I completed the entry with `### Additional Config ###` in code

Comment: I don't know why, but now it's works - maybe I had some syntax error

Comment: Just FYI: there's no need to rely on Typoscript here. You could simply have all that logic, i.e. the picture-tag, or img-tag with additional sources directly within your fluid template.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, it is easier to do it in your Fluid-Template.

You could write your own ViewHelper or plugin and feed it with your imagedata and then build your Images with something like this:

```
<picture>
     <f:for each="{sizes}" as="size">
         <source media="(min-width: {...}px)" 
                 srcset="{f:uri.image(...)}">
     </f:for>
     <img src="{f:uri.image(...)}" alt="{...}" title="{...}">
 </picture>
```